# C# HTTP Get request gives Error | Nowpayments API

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Method for Checking the payment from my nowpayments invoice.

```cs
var client2 = new HttpClient();
            var request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.nowpayments.io/v1/payment/" + paymentId);
            request2.Headers.Add("x-api-key", apiKey);
            var response2 = await client2.SendAsync(request2);
            response2.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Console.WriteLine(await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

```json
Response: "{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  x-dns-prefetch-control: off
  x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
  strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
  strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000
  x-download-options: noopen
  x-content-type-options: nosniff
  x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
  vary: Origin
  vary: Accept-Encoding
  CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
  Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=OdTo2JBrpASej8JsgICuTwKgyGmvadtradnnwieH8OI6lPFXH38c%2F5YwSg6jUfMQEnKGoTa6Q7TLI4rhrqYt8K0XkdOK0qX%2BsSFmmkF6qfkQqAK66fA46l6ci8gVXusvmuzjoQ%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
  NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
  CF-RAY: 7a330879af87b75b-AMS
  Date: Sun, 05 Mar 2023 14:26:17 GMT
  Server: cloudflare
  Content-Length: 82
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}"
```

I checked the value of the API URL and the APIKey. Both are correct.
I also checked the API via Postman and everything was successful.

I expected that I am getting the status of the the `createdPaymentInvoice`.

Comment: you might want to double check the value of `paymentId`. Also try using the same URL from postman in the code, instead of joining value of paymentId.

Comment: paymentId is right. When I use the same URL from Postman in the Code I get Stauscode: "OK". Thats weird..

Comment: I tried to change the URL like this `var request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.nowpayments.io/v1/payment/?iid=" + paymentId);` but than am getting StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'

Comment: I am getting the PaymentId through Regex. But I dont think that causes the issue. `Match match = Regex.Match(invoiceUrl, @"\d+$");

            if (match.Success)
            {
                paymentId = match.Value;

            }`

Comment: The service is returning 404 that means it is not able to find the payment record with the specified paymentid. That means the paymentid you have in the code is not correct. And you can only verify by observing the the value of paymentId either by debugging or logging it in the log file.